# DJango - File Upload - read - process & download

Tags: python, django

need your help!!!

I am trying to create a web app where user will upload the pdf files > read files > process it > write in excel > then auto download in users system.

Please do help with the code i am using py3.12 & django5

thanks in advance.

code for above isseu

Answer (score 0):

Far too much in that to show how to do it all, but in outline:

- A form with a file field will look after the user selecting the file and uploading it
- form_valid processing will read and process the file into excel
- You can send excel output to the user like this:

.

```
response = HttpResponse( content_type='application/excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={name}.xlsx'
data = self.get_wb_as_xlsx()
response.write(data)
return response
```

Where data is the generated xlsx file. I used openpyxl to write a workbook `self.wb` and then when that is complete,

```
def get_wb_as_xlsx( self):
    ''' returns text of wb (xlsx file content) '''
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile( suffix='.xlsx')
    self.wb.save( f.name)
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return data
```

This assumes that the processing doesn't take too much CPU time to reasonably execute in server context. Otherwise you should save the file, spawn a separate process to do the conversion (possibly written as a managementr command so all Django functionality is available), and tell the user to retrieve his results from a link, after (time estimate)

The link is to a view which checks whether the results are yet available, semds them to the user if they are, apologises and gives another time estimate and the same link if not.